# Proving a proposition which leads the irrationality of $\frac{\zeta(5)}{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

**Question** : Is the following $(\star)$ true for $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$ ?

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(ax^4+b\pi x^3+c{\pi}^{2}x^2)\log(\sin x)dx=0\Rightarrow  a=b=c=0\qquad(\star)\end{align}$$

**Motivation** : I've just been to able to prove the following theorem :

**Theorem** : If $(\star)$ is true, then $\frac{\zeta (5)}{\zeta (2)\zeta (3)}$ is an irrational number.

However, I can't prove that $(\star)$ is true. Can anyone help?

**Remark** : This question has been [asked previously on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533263/proving-a-proposition-which-leads-the-irrationality-of-frac-zeta5-zeta2) without receiving any answers, where you can see the proof of the above theorem.

Comment: It may be helpful to mention that you know how to evaluate the integral, but it doesn't help in proving the desired property.

Comment: I like the question, but unfortunately I doubt this is progress towards proving the irrationality.  (Of course I'd be very happy to be proved wrong.)  By splitting (*) apart into the $a$, $b$, and $c$ pieces, you are trying to show that these three integrals are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.  As you note on math.SE, they are $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combinations of $\log 2$, $\zeta(3)/\pi^2$, and $\zeta(5)/\pi^4$.  In particular, if $\zeta(5)/(\zeta(2)\zeta(3))$ were irrational then the three integrals wouldn't be $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent.

Comment: In order to prove (*), you'd need to have some way of detecting when an integral vanishes.  I imagine the reason why there have been no answers on math.SE is that nobody has any idea how to do it: it's hard to prove an integral is nonzero without some special structure to help, and it's not clear to me what to use here.  But I could just be missing something...

Comment: After substituting $x=\pi u$, the question concerns $$\int_0^{1/2}(au^4+bu^3+cu^2)\log\sin\pi u\,du$$ which seems a little more pleasant to me.